# Database/API for airline ticket prices

Tags: air-travel, airlines, price, gds

Some airlines have price calendar like the following:

[image]

But how can I get prices for various airlines/directions, for next 6 months, in one API/database?

[Amadeus has API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search) for getting info for one direction, one day, but since I need much more data, this API is very non-efficient for me

Where can I find suitable service, and how much does it cost?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about travel but API for airline prices

Comment: https://www.theverge.com/2017/11/1/16591850/google-ita-matrix-shut-down-qpx-express-api lists a few options to explore

Comment: I would migrate this but I doubt there is a suitable stack exchange site. In my view not Aviation as it is not about flying and I do not think any of the programming sites will fit.

Comment: maybe [opendata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?